# Dynamic sitemap.xml generation with Ember

Tags: ember.js, sails.js, ember-cli

I would like to deploy my Ember-CLI blog soon.
It will use prerender.io to cache static versions of my page.
The backend runs with Sails.js.

How do you generate/serve sitemap.xml dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [`ember-cli-sitemap`](https://github.com/klclee/ember-cli-sitemap) does what you want.